# Do people know more words or proper nouns?

Tags: vocabulary, proper-nouns

I'm curious if the average adult knows more words in their language (excluding proper nouns), or more proper nouns? At first I'm inclined to think the former, but then I think of all the names I know: names of people, places/streets, institutions/companies, brands, titles of books/movies, etc. I know this is a difficult question but I'm curious how to estimate it.

Answer (score 3):

Words, definitely.

[A 2016 study](https://www.upi.com/Science_News/2016/08/16/Most-US-adults-have-vocabulary-of-more-than-42000-words/2801471361934/) suggests that your average 20-year-old knows over 42,000 lemmata ("basic" words, like *run*, as opposed to *running* and *runs*). Multiply that by three if you want to include "non-basic" words: as a rule of thumb, English nouns have two forms, verbs four, adjectives three.

While there are a lot of proper nouns out there in the world, it's unlikely any individual will know more than 126,000 of them.